# Primes Between Squares of Primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers, prime-gaps

Is this problem still open? I know that Henri Brocard conjectured that there are at least four primes in the interval between each pair of consecutive squares of primes from nine onward.
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrocardsConjecture.html

I know that Brocard's conjecture remains open. I am asking if there is yet a proof for only one prime between each pair of consecutive squares of primes. Is this a problem with or without a name? Where can I find a reference about it or any information on progress made on it?

Comment: It sounds like Legendre's conjecture restricted to the primes.

Comment: Right. It is similar to Legendre's conjecture, but weaker.

Comment: There are q^2-p^2 numbers between the squares of primes p and q. Of these, the even numbers aren't prime. Neither the multiples of 3 among the odd ones. Or the multiples of 5 among those that are odd and not multiples of 3, and so on, until the multiples of p. All the others are prime. So the number of primes between p^2 and q^2 must be (q^2-p^2) X 1/2*2/3*4/5*6/7*10/11* ... (p-1)/p.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reference, among others, on such problems is the paper [On Legendre’s, Brocard’s, Andrica’s, and Oppermann’s Conjectures](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.1323) by German Andres Paz. His "Conjecture $1$" related to Brocard's conjecture as follows. Let denote $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$ two successive primes greater than $2$. Since $p_{n+1}-p_n\ge 2$, we know that there is a positive integer $k$ with $p_n<k<p_{n+1}$. Hence we have $p_n^2<k^2<p_{n+1}^2$. By conjecture $1$ there are at least two primes between $p_n^2$ and $k^2$, and between $k^2$ and $p_{n+1}^2$. Hence we have at least $4$ primes between $p_n^2$ and $p_{n+1}^2$. Hence Brocard's conjecture follows.

So I think, Conjecture $1$, Brocard's conjecture, and "your conjecture" (which is a variant of these) are still open.